Cookie not working with webkit using Leptos
I'm working on an app using Leptos as the framework, I need to set some cookies but for some reason the code I use works on Chromium and Firefox, but fails on WebKit.
use leptos::*;
use wasm_bindgen::JsCast;

fn set_cookie(name: &str, value: &str) {
    let document = leptos::document()
      .dyn_into::<web_sys::HtmlDocument>()
      .unwrap_throw();
    let cookie = format!(
        "{}={}; SameSite=Lax; Secure; Path=/; Max-Age=31536000",
        name,
        value
    );
    document.set_cookie(&cookie).unwrap_throw();
}

Does anyone have an idea why it fails on Webkit but not Chromium or Firefox ?
